# How to get the total items in an array(array length) in dust.js

Tags: dust.js

I can't seem to figure out(I'm pretty sure that I'm over thinking or not thinking here) a way to get the length of an array in the following example. Can anyone please help me, or direct me to a good tutorial. https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Dust-Tutorial has mentioned the {@size} helper but does not have any examples.

```
<ul total-tems={#items.length/}>
{#items}
    <li class="item-{$idx}">{.title}</li>
{/items}
</ul>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yep, I was clearly overlooking. I was not including ( require('dustjs-helpers'); ) in order to use

```
<ul total-tems="{@size key=items /}">
```

Hope this will help others out as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if is it a new feature of dustjs but now you can simply use `{items.length}` to access the array length with no need of helpers.

Comment: Great! Looks like they added the feature.